# Google Sheets Chart of one line with two values

Tags: charts, google-sheets

My data looks like this:

```
A   B
3   5000
2   6218
4   9435
```

I need to create a chart where A is the number of points/block size and B is the Value of each point.

For example, the date above will create a line graph where the 2 first points will have the value of 5000, the next 2 points will have the value of 6218, and the next 4 points will have the value of 9435.

The graph I need will look like the automatic one that will be generated for this data:

```
5000
5000
5000
6218
6218
9435
9435
9435
9435
```

Comment: What methods have you already tried and/or used?

Answer (score 0):

use the original data table to build a new data table.
for each row in the original table, add a row to the new table however many times `'A'` represents.

```
var x = 0;
for (var row = 0; row < rawData.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
  for (var a = 0; a < rawData.getValue(row, 0); a++) {
    chartData.addRow([x, rawData.getValue(row, 1)]);
    x++;
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var rawData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['A', 'B'],
    [3, 5000],
    [2, 6218],
    [4, 9435]
  ]);

  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'X');
  chartData.addColumn('number', 'Y');

  var x = 0;
  for (var row = 0; row < rawData.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
    for (var a = 0; a < rawData.getValue(row, 0); a++) {
      chartData.addRow([x, rawData.getValue(row, 1)]);
      x++;
    }
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  chart.draw(chartData, {
    height: 288,
    pointSize: 4,
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```